# Http cache by vary on a custom header

Tags: php, symfony, cache-control

I'm researching **http cache** by using **Vary header**, my website has to serve a response content *base on a user preferred currency*, they can choose displayed currency from the currency selection on my site and I'm using session to store their chosen currency instead of using query parameter in the url.

I want to cache responses base on currencies, I created the custom header for every **response** `x-currency: currency_value` and set the `vary` header `vary: x-currency`, to tell the `http cache` to create a different cached content by currency.

but I don't understand at the point, when a user send a request to the `http cache`, that **request header** is not included the custom header `x-currency: current_value`, so how the `http cache` knows a preferred currency to serve the correct response to user ?

I also think about vary on cookie, but it seems to serve a cached response to unique user not for the group of users that have the same preferred currency.

please show me what I misunderstood or any alternative solutions to achieve that !

Answer (score 1):

You have misunderstood what header the `Vary` header should indicate. [Vary](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-7.1.4):

> describes what **parts of a
> request message**, aside from the method, Host header field, and
> request target, might influence the origin server's process for
> selecting and representing this response.

In this case, you say you're:

> using session to store their chosen currency

That means that the response you're selecting is influenced by the `Cookie` header that the user's session was sent in. You should therefore send:

```
Vary: cookie
```

in the response.

As a point of design, you mention that you've chosen session storage:

> instead of using query parameter in the url.

and also mention:

> I also think about vary on cookie, but it seems to serve a cached response to unique user not for the group of users that have the same preferred currency.

You're right. Using a query parameter would be significantly more cacheable, as requests for the same currency could be reused. `Vary: cookie` is essentially the same as `Cache-control: private`, as no two users will have the same session cookie.